# Hardsubbing ASS onto MPEG4

Tags: video, video-quality, mpeg, matroska

I have an ASS as the subtitle stream (with these fonts: - Orotund, jagb_***.tff, jagw*_**.ttf, JUST.ttf, Gabrielle.ttf) in an MKV.

What technique should I use to hardsub this subtitle stream onto the MPEG4 (ISO/AVC) without losing quality?

Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo) has an amazing article on burning the subs into the videos.

I trust ffmpeg to be very careful with (the lack of) quality loss.

Given you are dealing with ASS, here are the important bits,

> You can burn text subtitles (hardsubs) with one of two filters: subtitles or ass.
>
> ass filter
>
> Same as the subtitles filter, except that it doesn’t require libavcodec and libavformat to work. This filter requires ffmpeg to be compiled with --enable-libass. On the other hand, it is limited to ​ASS (Advanced Substation Alpha) subtitles files. See the ​ass video filter documentation for more details.
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf "ass=subtitle.ass" out.avi
> ```
>
> If your subtitle is in SubRip, MicroDVD or any other supported text subtitles, you have to convert it to ASS before using this filter:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i subtitle.srt subtitle.ass
> ```
>
> Windows users will have to ​setup font paths to get libass to work

Comment: ~10 years later! - Ah but that looks right (obviously I don't have the files anymore to test, but your syntax seems likely to work)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's impossible to hardcode subs without quality loss.

Unless there's a new technique developed in the last 4 years, the file needs to be converted to a lossless type then the subs need to be coded frame by frame and then compress again.

So: There is no technique that may be used to hardsub onto a compressed video without losing [more] quality.

Comment: Well which technique has the least amount of quality loss?

Comment: I can point the way, but I can't explain the technique - I used to do this a looooooooooooooong time ago. 
Try checking [this](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/325288-How-to-embed-subtitles-into-mkv-STEP-BY-STEP-using-MKVMERGE-and-MKVEXTRACT) out. The concept is taking the video OUT from the MKV conteiner and then hardcode it.

Comment: I cannot downvote yet, but this is a bad suggestion. ffmpeg has native support for hardcoding subs, and given ffmpeg is very careful with the losses, it's very much possible to burn in subs without overall quality loss